# simple_form many to many association as tree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am trying to build a UI for updating a model ("Profile") that has a many to many relationship with another model ("Category"). The "Category" model has a self referential relationship with itself for "Sub Categories".

In my simple_form I want to display the categories as checkboxes with their sub categories nested below them as check boxes.

In my current code all I have is this for the association field:

```
= f.association :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: @categories
```

I am just retrieving the top level categories into the variable @categories.

I'm not sure where to go from here. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Ancestry**

We've done this before using the `ancestry` gem:

[image]

[image]

The problem you have is your self-referential association won't give you the scope required to create a "real" nested dropdown; it has to be able to consider all the nested data.

Instead, what we did was to firstly employee the `ancestry` gem, and then use a `partial` and `helper` to get the nested dropdown affect:

```
#app/models/category.rb
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_ancestry
end
```

[image]

---

**Display**

If you store the dependent data like that, it allows you to create a `partial`-based nested effect:

```
#app/views/admin/categories/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: collection } %>


#app/views/categories/_category.html.erb
<!-- Categories -->
<ol class="categories">
    <% collection.arrange.each do |category, sub_item| %>
        <li>
            <!-- Category -->
            <div class="category">
                <%= link_to category.title, edit_admin_category_path(category) %>
                <%= link_to "+", admin_category_new_path(category), title: "New Categorgy", data: {placement: "bottom"} %>
            </div>

            <!-- Children -->
            <% if category.has_children? %>
                <%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: category.children } %>
            <% end %>

        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

---

**Dropdown**

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
Class ApplicationHelper
    def nested_dropdown(items)
        result = []
        items.map do |item, sub_items|
            result << [('- ' * item.depth) + item.name, item.id]
            result += nested_dropdown(sub_items) unless sub_items.blank?
        end
        result
    end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
= f.input :categories, as: :select, collection: nested_dropdown(@categories)
```

Comment: Hi Rich. Thanks for your answer. I hadn't looked in to the ancestry gem too much so this is good. The only issue with it is that I need to make multiple selections in my form which is why I was wanting to use checkboxes instead of a dropdown. Do you think this same approach could be applied for multiple selections using checkboxes?

Comment: Would the multiple checkboxes be dependent? IE if you Select checkbox 1, checkbox 2 will update to reflect new change?

Comment: No you will select each individually.

Comment: Okay - so what would be in checkbox 1, as opposed to checkbox 2?

Comment: Ok just thinking it through again. I would say yes the if the "Sub category" is selected then the parent category must automatically be selected. But if the parent category is selected it won't automatically select all of the sub categories for the parent. The main thing though is to be able to display the categories in their hierarchy some how so that multiple selections can be made.